# The different pull with Sync when we pull the source code from Azure DevOps

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

When I make some change in the Azure DevOps server, then I pull the source code from the Azure DevOps server, then I noticed that I can select `pull` under the **Incoming Commits**:

[image]

Then I can also click the `Sync` to pull the source code. What is different?

Besides, what is the different the `pull` under the **Branch** with pull under the **Incoming Commits**?

I am new to Azure DevOps, so if I ask an unreasonable question, please point out.

Comment: It seems those two `pull` do the same things, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio#sync-with-others, but I have not find the different Sync and pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sync** does a **Pull** then a **Push** from/to the remote.

**Pull** will just **Pull** (Fetch and merge) from the remote.

The 2 Pull's do the [same thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio#sync-with-others):

> You can download the latest changes to the branch you are on using the Pull link. (There are two Pull links, one near the top and one in the Incoming Commits section. You can use either one as they both do the same thing.)

[image: Sync Changes]